# How to create banner images that pan across screen using Xcode/Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimage, banner

How do you create a banner (say, above a `UITableView` or something) that will switch images after a given time, or upon swipe. It then recycles through after a set number of images. See the below provided example from the IF app).

Also, I'm not necessarily looking for code here, but simply general features of Xcode I'd use to make it happen (ie, `UIImageView` within a `ContainerView` with gesture recognizers or something). Any ideas?

Here's the first image:
   [image: First Image]

Then the beginning of the transition:
   [image: Begin Transition]

Then the second image in place:
   [image: Final Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/) is an example of how to get that exact behavior using UIPageViewController. From the [documenation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/):

> A page view controller lets the user navigate between pages of content, where each page is managed by its own view controller object. Navigation can be controlled programmatically by your app or directly by the user using gestures. When navigating from page to page, the page view controller uses the transition that you specify to animate the change.

Comment: Not a problem at all!